# How do I add a List<String> property to my greendao generator?

Tags: android, greendao

I'm trying to generate my models using the greendao generator and I'm not quite sure how to add a property that accepts a `List<String>`

I know how to add a `List<Model>` using the `addToMany` but what if I need to store an `ArrayList` inside one of my models?

Something like this:

```
Entity tags = schema.addEntity("Tags");
    tags.implementsInterface("android.os.Parcelable");
    tags.addLongProperty("tagId").primaryKey().autoincrement();
    tags.addLongProperty("date");
    tags.addArrayStringProperty("array"); // something like this
```

I was thinking of creating another entity to store all the values of the array, and doing the `ToMany` like this

```
Entity myArray = schema.addEntity("MyArray");
    myArray.implementsInterface("android.os.Parcelable");
    myArray.addLongProperty("myArrayId").primaryKey().autoincrement();
    myArray.addLongProperty("id").notNull().getProperty();
    Property tagId = myArray.addLongProperty("tagId").getProperty();

ToMany tagToMyArray = tag.addToMany(myArray, tagId);
tagToMyArray.setName("tags");
myArray.addToOne(tag, tagId);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can serialise that ArrayList and then save as a string property in greenDAO table.

```
String arrayString = new Gson().toJson(yourArrayList);
```

and then retrieve it back like this

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>(){}.getType();
List<String> arrayList = new Gson().fromJson(stringFromDb, listType)
```

Comment: Thanks for such a simple answer

Answer (score 3):

Another way.You can use @convert annotation.

```
@Entity
public class User {
@Id
private Long id;

@Convert(converter = RoleConverter.class, columnType = Integer.class)
private Role role;

public enum Role {
    DEFAULT(0), AUTHOR(1), ADMIN(2);

    final int id;

    Role(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

public static class RoleConverter implements PropertyConverter<Role, Integer> {
    @Override
    public Role convertToEntityProperty(Integer databaseValue) {
        if (databaseValue == null) {
            return null;
        }
        for (Role role : Role.values()) {
            if (role.id == databaseValue) {
                return role;
            }
        }
        return Role.DEFAULT;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseValue(Role entityProperty) {
        return entityProperty == null ? null : entityProperty.id;
    }
}
}
```